# I applied W2V on ML Algorithms. It gives error of negative value for NB and gives 0.48 accuracy for for all the other algorithms. How come?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, random-forest, word2vec, naivebayes

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import time
# Skip-gram model (sg = 1)
size = 1000
window = 3
min_count = 1
workers = 3
sg = 1

word2vec_model_file = 'word2vec_' + str(size) + '.model'
start_time = time.time()
stemmed_tokens = pd.Series(df['STEMMED_TOKENS']).values
# Train the Word2Vec Model
w2v_model = Word2Vec(stemmed_tokens, min_count = min_count, size = size, workers = workers, window = window, sg = sg)
print("Time taken to train word2vec model: " + str(time.time() - start_time))
w2v_model.save(word2vec_model_file)
```

This is the code I have written. I applied this file on all ML algorithms for binary classification but all algorithms gives same result 0.48. How does it possible ? ANd also this result is very poor compare to BERT and TFIDF scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector `size` of 1000 dimensions is very uncommon, and would require massive amounts of data to train. For example, the famous `GoogleNews` vectors were for 3 million words, trained on something like 100 billion corpus words - and still only 300 dimensions. Your `STEMMED_TOKENS` may not be enough data to justify 100-dimensional vectors, much less 300 or 1000.

A choice of `min_count=1` is a bad idea. This algorithm can't learn anything valuable from words that only appear a few times. Typically people get better results by discarding rare words entirely, as the default `min_count=5` will do. (If you have a lot of data, you're likely to *increase* this value to discard even more words.)

Are you examining the model's size or word-to-word results at all to ensure it's doing what you expect? Despite your colum being named `STEMMED_TOKENS`, I don't see any actual splitting-into-tokens, and the `Word2Vec` class expects each text to be a *list-of-strings*, **not** a string.

Finally, without seeing all your other choices for feeding word-vector-enriched data to your other classification steps, it is possible (likely even) that there are other errors there.

Given that a binary-classification model can always get at least 50% accuracy by simply classifying every example with whichever class is more common, any accuracy result less than 50% should immediately cause suspicions of major problems in your process like:

- misalignment of examples & labels
- insufficient/unrepresentative training data
- some steps not running at all due to data-prep or invocation errors